# Making either/or cfargument required

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

There are two form elements on a product insertion page that can specify the manufacturer of a product. One is a drop-down list and the other is a textfield.

The user MUST provide the manufacturer of the product when they want to submit it for insertion into the database. So either they select it from the drop-down list or they enter the name of the Manufacturer in the textfield. Client-side JavaScript validation can ensure that at least one is filled in.

However in my CFC that takes care of the insertion, how do I ensure that at least one of those fields has values? Pseudo-code style I'm thinking along the lines of:

```
<cfargument name="ManufacturerID" type="numeric" required="true"/> // drop-down value
OR 
<cfargument name="Manufacturer" type="string" required="true"/>    // textfield value
```

Essentially my question is how do I server-side validate form values whos required status is dependent on the value of another form element existing or not existing?

Comment: You could make them both optional and then validate them manually, throwing an exception if they are not valid

Comment: @KevinB if go that route, how do I throw the same error that ColdFusion would throw if a required argument is not present?

Comment: That i don't know, would need to throw a couple myself to see what the error is before i could replicate it.

Comment: If one is a drop down list `<select>` and the other is an `<input type="text` then both fields will exist when you submit. It is true that one or both could be blank, but they will exist. I don't think you are dealing with a scenario were variables to a function are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you add validation to BOTH the UI and to the cfc.

First, I recommend method level validation to ensure your function works properly when called from any application call.

You have to declare both arguments in your CFC if you want to have them accessible for help/hint, java-documentation etc, but there is no reason you need to if they are optional.

You can have undeclared overloaded arguments as well and enforce that either one or the other are sent in within the function similar to what Fish Below the Ice has suggested.

For declared arguments, there is no need, nay, no reason to check with `structKeyExists()` because a documented argument key will always exists. It would only be useful to check for undocumented overloaded arguments.

Using CF9+ cfscript style (you can equally do this in tags if you want):

```
public function insertProduct(numeric ManufacturerId , string ManufacturerName ) {
  if(!isDefined('Arguments.MfgId') && !isDefined('Arguments.MfgName') 
      throw("You must provide either the ManufacturerId or the ManufacturerName argument", "Validation");

  // Continue with your code
  return 'Your Result';

}
```

Secondly, it is just good practise to pre-validate at the UI level to

- Allow friendly UI feedback immediately.
- Reduce calls to server that you already know will fail.

For the UI. I would use JS to do this rather than wait for the form to be submitted.

```
<form id='ManForm' action='somewhere_else' method='post'>
  <label>Select A Manufacturer:</label>
  <select name='ManufacturerId' id='ManufacturerId'>
    <option value='0'>-- Select --</option>
    <option value='1'>1: JohnnyDear</option>
    <option value='2'>2: Cattypillar</option>
  </select>
  <label>Search By Name:</label>
  <input type='text' name='ManufacturerName' id='ManufacturerName'/>
  <button id='submitForm'>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

and in js (with jQuery library included):

```
$(function() {
  // BIND ON CLICK TO BUTTON
  $('#submitForm').click(function(event) {

      // VALIDATE
      var _mfrId = $('#ManufacturerId');
      var _mfrNm = $('#ManufacturerName');
      if(_mfrId.val() == 0 && _mfrNm.val().length < 1) {
          // Inform User of issue
          alert('You must select a Manufacturer by Id or\n enter a Name before submitting');
          return false;
      }

      // SUBMIT - If validation did not return false, the form will submit
      $('#submitForm').submit();
  });
})
```

You could further encapsulate and alter the javascript to do much more interesting things but this will get you started. I've included a jsfiddle link to show this UI code in action as well: http://jsfiddle.net/n12ugzwo/2/

Lastly, your form handler needs to do some basic validation and mapping to your cfc call.
If the user defeated the js validation, you would still want your handler to check. You also may want to determine WHICH value is used if both come in. You might also add some UI/js validation/help to let the user know this as well.

In the form handler (action) page:

```
<cfscript>
  if(isDefined('Form.ManufacturerId')) {
    if(len(Form.ManufacturerName)) { // Any value gt 0 will return true
      Variables.ProductInsertResult = insertProduct(ManufacturerName: Form.ManufacturerName);
    } else if(Form.ManufacturerId) { // Any value gt 0 will return true
      Variables.ProductInsertResult = insertProduct(ManufacturerId: Form.ManufacturerId);
    } else {
      writeoutput('You must select a Manufacturer by Id or enter a Name before submitting.<br>');
      writeoutput('Please go back and resubmit with valid entries.');
    }
  }
</cfsript>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation of Kevin B's comment.  As he said, make both arguments optional.  However, do your validation as part of your form processing page, not the cfc.

```
 <cfif len(form.ManufacturerId) gt 0 
 or len(form.Manufacturer) gt 0>
 call your cfc
 <cfelse>
 display something to user.
 </cfif>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this in my component:

```
<cffunction name="insertProduct" ...>
  ...
  <cfargument name="ManufacturerID" required="false" type="numeric">
  <cfargument name="Manufacturer required="false" type="string">
  ...
  <cfif NOT (
    (StructKeyExists(arguments,"ManufacturerID") AND isNumeric(arguments.ManufacturerID))
    OR 
    (StructKeyExists(arguments,"Manufacturer") AND len(trim(arguments.Manufacturer)) GT 0)
  )>
    <cfthrow type="ValidationError" message="Either 'ManufacturerID' or 'Manufacturer' must be supplied to the insertProduct function">
  </cfif>
  ...
```

Comment: @williambq: I added some further validation.

Comment: That will work. But your check with structkeyexists() are superlative. Because you declared them with cfarguments, the keys will always exist. They just may not be defined (have a value of not undefined). You could simply cut those out and check the value via isNumeric/len or isDefined('Arguments.ManufacturerId')... Btw, isDefined is generally not a bad function to use as long as you check for fully scoped variables (ie: do not use isDefined('ManufacturerId') as this loops through available scopes and may give unexpected results).